# Using (scp | rsync) to pull specific files while creating folder structure at same time?

Tags: bash, unix, rsync, scp

I have a big project hosted on a server that has specific files that I want to copy to my local machine in the same folder structure but only the specific file I want. My current command to find these files is (while in the project on the server):

```
find ./ -type f -name '*_out.csv' ! -path './*/doc/*' 2>/dev/null
```

Which produces a list like this (truncated for brevity):

```
./validation/Riso_AN8/analysis/Riso_AN8_out.csv
./validation/FUMEXII_Regate/analysis/Regate_smeared_out.csv
./validation/FUMEXII_Regate/analysis/Regate_discrete_out.csv
./validation/IFA_432/analysis/rod3/IFA_432_rod3_out.csv
./validation/IFA_432/analysis/rod1/IFA_432_rod1_out.csv
./validation/IFA_432/analysis/rod2/IFA_432_rod2_out.csv
./validation/LOCA_REBEKA_cladding_burst_tests/analysis/rebeka_2d_06MPa/rebeka_singlerod_2d_06MPa_out.csv
./validation/LOCA_REBEKA_cladding_burst_tests/analysis/rebeka_2d_06MPa/rebeka_singlerod_2d_06MPa_tm_out.csv
./validation/LOCA_REBEKA_cladding_burst_tests/analysis/rebeka_2d_08MPa/rebeka_singlerod_2d_08MPa_tm_out.csv
```

I would like to use `scp` or `rsync` to pull these files to my local machine and create the folder structure without anything else in them. What would be the best way to go about this? I have a **ton** of files so I don't really want to create the folder structure before hand. I also can't pull the entire project from the server because it's huge and the system admins will get mad at me.

Is there a way to pull these files while simultaneously creating the folder structure on my local machine?

Comment: Extract the directory portion of the pathname with `dirname` and use `mkdir -p` to create the local directory structure. Then use `rsync` or `scp` to copy the file to that directory.

Comment: I think you may be able to do it with just `rsync` and the `-include` and `-exclude` options to make it just copy the files you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage `rsync` and I would probably call `find` via `ssh` using the `basedir` to pull the files from in a *process substitution*. You can then feed a `while` loop to read each filename found on the server, obtain the path and create the path on the local machine below the current directory using `mkdir -p` (with validation). Then you can call `rsync` to pull the file from the server to the correct directory using `rsync -uav`. For example you could do something similar to:

```
#!/bin/bash

server=${1:-yourserver}       ## your server name
basedir=${2:-/path/to/files}  ## the base directory to run find on server

while read -r line; do        ## read line at a time from find output on server
    dname="${line%/*}"        ## separate directory name
    mkdir -p "$dname" || {    ## create/validate directory from remote file
        printf "error: unable to create '%s'.\n", "$dname" >&2
        continue
    }
    rsync -uav "$server:$line" "$dname" ## rsync file to correct directory
done < <(ssh "$server" "find $basedir -type f -name '*_out.csv' ! -path './*/doc/*' 2>/dev/null")
```

Then just call the script on the local machine providing the server name as the first argument and the base directory where the files are located on the server. Make sure you change directory on the local machine to the directory you want to create the remote directory structure under. This presumes your `find` call (executed on the server by `ssh` from the local machine) returns the list of files you wish to copy to your local machine.

This is not nearly as efficient as a single `rsync` call, but if your `find` command produces branches under the remote directory tree that have multi-levels of directories before the filename that would not otherwise be created on the local machine, you will have to manually ensure you create those paths before calling `rsync` on the remote file.

Comment: Re your last sentence: You mean I have something defined in my script like, `line=($(ssh -qn user@server "find /path/to/files -type f -name '*_out.csv' -not -path '*/doc/*' 2>/dev/null"))`, which is what I will iterate over using the while loop?

Comment: Yes. And see the last paragraph I added. If you are just copying whole directories, then a single `rsync` call is all you need (as Barmar shows in his answer). However, if you are copying scattered files from a nested directory structure on the remote machine, then you will need to loop over the files (as above) and manually create the paths to copy to --- `rsync` will not normally create nested directories to copy a file (it will if you are copying the entire base directory).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a ton. The other answer seemed like it would work but it ended up copying everything not just the `*_out.csv` files. Do you have a resource you could point me to for the `< <` syntax? I have never seen this in bash and am curious how to use it in the future.

Comment: Sure, that is just a bash feature called *process substitution*. [Process Substitution (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) You redirect the output of the process substitution to feed the `while` loop just like redirecting a file. With a file you would do `< file`, with process substitution you use `< <(process)`. With *process substitution* there must be a space between the `< <`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with `rsync`'s `--exclude` and `--include` options.

```
rsync --recursive --include '*_out.csv' --exclude '*/doc/*' server:path/to/remote/dir path/to/local/dir
```

Comment: That's normally how I would do it. The only thing I wasn't clear on is whether you would have stray branches of the directory tree that were not present on the local machine that wouldn't automatically be created if the initial portion of the path didn't already exist (e.g. starting with an empty directory on the local machine and attempting to `rsync -uav /path/to/file/with/several/dirs/to/file.txt`. In that case you would need to create the part of `/path/to/file/with/several/dirs/to` locally before the `rsync` call).

Comment: `rsync` will create any needed intermediate directories automatically.

Comment: Except if the intermediate path does not already exist and you are copying a single file by name, e.g. (`rsync -uav valkyrie:/home/david/tmp/ttt/CMakeFiles/TicTacToe.dir/link.txt ttt/CMakeFiles/TicTacToe.dir/`) If `ttt/CMakeFiles/TicTacToe.dir/` doesn't exist locally, it results in `rsync: mkdir "/home/david/tmp/ttt/CMakeFiles/TicTacToe.dir" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: But I'm not copying individual files by name. I'm using the `--recursive` option to copy an entire directory hierarchy, but filtering it to just the files he wants.

Comment: Yes, correct I know, that was just the difference I saw in the question and was confused if I interpreted it the question wrong. I took it to elicit all `*_out.csv` files that may have been scattered all over the place under the base directory the questioner was looking at.

Comment: And my solution lets `rsync` find all those files using `--include`, rather than listing them separately with `find`. That then allows `rsync` to reconstruct the directory hierarchy properly.

Comment: If his `find` criteria were something that `rsync` couldn't emulate, your more complex solution would be necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to include multiple `--exclude` options? Would I add just another `--exclude '*/recover_files_cp/*'` to the command?

Comment: Yes. You can also put all the exclusions in a file and use `--exclude-from=filename`.